# Revel app doesn´t compile in heroku

Tags: git, heroku, go, revel

I am pushing to my heroku app after two months without push anything, and I am finding some compilation errors. This is the output when I try `git push heroku master'

```
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 16.64 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 25 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Revel app detected
remote: -----> Using go1.4
remote: -----> Running: go get -tags heroku ./...
remote: # ndc-console-test/app/controllers
remote: app/controllers/app.go:160: c.RenderJson undefined (type App has no field or method RenderJson)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:170: c.RenderArgs undefined (type App has no field or method RenderArgs)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:171: c.RenderArgs undefined (type App has no field or method RenderArgs)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:172: c.RenderArgs undefined (type App has no field or method RenderArgs)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:173: c.RenderArgs undefined (type App has no field or method RenderArgs)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:191: c.RenderArgs undefined (type App has no field or method RenderArgs)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:192: c.RenderArgs undefined (type App has no field or method RenderArgs)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:193: c.RenderArgs undefined (type App has no field or method RenderArgs)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:194: c.RenderArgs undefined (type App has no field or method RenderArgs)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:195: c.RenderArgs undefined (type App has no field or method RenderArgs)
remote: app/controllers/app.go:195: too many errors
remote: # ndc-console-test/app/routes
remote: app/routes/routes.go:15: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("App.Index", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:22: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("App.Ndc", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:29: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("App.FlightPrice", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:36: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("App.SeatAvailability", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:43: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("App.OrderCreateRQ", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:50: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("App.ServicePrice", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:57: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("App.OrderRetrieve", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:64: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("App.OrderChange", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:71: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("App.OrderCancel", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:83: revel.MainRouter.Reverse("TestRunner.Index", args).Url undefined (type *revel.ActionDefinition has no field or method Url)
remote: app/routes/routes.go:83: too many errors
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Revel app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to ndc-console.
```

The app worked the last time I pushed and I didn´t modify the files where the errors are found... and the methods (in some cases) and fields (in other cases) should exist.

Thank in advance.

PS: The revel buildpack is added in the heroku app.

### EDIT

Could be the go and/or revel version?? I have installed revel 0.13.1 and I had seen that v0.14.0 had been released (just less than two months ago). About golang I reinstall it and I have the latest version.

Comment: It is exactly that, `v0.14.0` includes braking changes like `RenderArgs` -> `ViewArgs` and `RenderJson` -> `RenderJSON`. See more here: https://github.com/revel/revel/releases/tag/v0.14.0. You either need to updated your code to be compatible with 0.14 or you need to specify in your Godpes or whatever vendoring you're using that your app needs revel 0.13.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva I am going to try it.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva it works... if you want you can change your comment to an answer. It is the solution.

Comment: I've only confirmed what you already suspected, so feel free to write the answer.